# R heatmap3 not scale strictly with zero equal to white

Tags: r, heatmap

```
heatmap3(mydataframe,useRaster=FALSE,Rowv=NA,Colv=NA,balanceColor=TRUE)
```

above is my code with heatmap3, I have set balanceColor to true in order to make it scales by 0 equal to white color. However, in my plot I still see some positive number in blue which should be red. How can I strictly make it scale by 0 = white?
[image]

For example look at picture below, it's based on a 5*50 matrix, look at bottom left which is (1,1) in the matrix:

and the number for first row is:

```
0.0005827946
0.001250024
0.002329636
0.001855301
0.001969714
0.003024985
0.002757383
0.002068112
0.0009109025
0.001063462
0.002285884
0.00307274
0.004101426
0.004551557
0.004115376
0.004671118
0.005293749
0.00557376
0.007052164
0.007841631
0.009168137
0.009893955
0.01055715
0.01059484
0.01095319
0.01154479
0.01269292
0.01304255
0.01382814
0.01362723
0.01489438
0.01553581
0.01553376
0.01586031
0.01661485
0.01617821
0.01664207
0.01765575
0.01840176
0.01949774
0.02048166
0.02049127
0.02112663
0.02245583
0.02381742
0.02331836
0.02384575
0.02326776
0.02353378
0.02451009
```

all of them are positive yet the plot gives me blue that should stand for negative number.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that clearly demonstrates the problem.

Comment: hi Flick i just added example, please take a look

Comment: I still can't copy/paste and run the code so that's not very helpful. But note that the documentation for the `balanceColor=` parameter says it balances around the median, not 0.